# Playing disc-based games from other countries

Tags: region-lock, ps4

If I buy a playstation 4 from America and bring it back with me to South Africa, will it be able to play games I buy on discs?

Comment: And wat about the xbox one

Answer (score 2):

The PS4 **isn't** region locked for digital or disc-based games. Games from other regions **will** work on any console but [this article](http://www.siliconera.com/2013/10/30/massive-playstation-4-faq-answers-questions/) advises the use of games from the region the PS4 is bought, so in your case, America.

It's also worth noting that the PS4 **is** region locked for Blu-rays though. Confirmation [here](http://n4g.com/news/1377707/ps4-blu-ray-player-is-region-locked-for-films#c-8372688).